# Get top rows from relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 2 models: `Video`, `Country` and want to retrieve the top 5 videos for each country ordered by number of views, and want to do that using the video model not the country model so i shall start with

```
$videos = Video::with('user')->orderBy('views', 'desc')->get();
```

So the code shall return videos from the top 5 for reach country

and will be appreciate if the solution that starts with `County::with('videos')` is
given

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [N related models per parent](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/)

Comment: @RahulGovind Thanks, that's what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

This should help, it return videos without iterating any loops.

```
 $countries = Country::with(['videos' => function($query) {
     $query->orderBy('views', 'desc')->take(5);
 }])->get();
```

**You must need this loop to get videos**

```
$topVideos = [];
foreach ($countries as $country) {
   $topVideos[] = $country->videos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$countries = Country::with(['videos' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy('views', 'desc');
    }])
    ->get();

foreach ($countries as $country) {
    $top_5_videos = $country->videos->take(5);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's get only 5 rows for a random country, the other countries get non

Comment: try without `take(5)` then if it works, limit collection when you retrieve videos

Comment: The last answer is working, but i need an answer to avoid loop and extra time, so i am looking for pure eloquent solution

Comment: as in this post you can do it by creating a new relationship and use both orderBy and limit function inside that. link to post: https://codeontrack.com/limit-results-hasmany-relationship-query-eager-loading-laravel/ . Otherwise it's not possible according to my knowledge